# Mongoose document delete automatically after one month

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just want to keep for one month after client-user will delete document particular document

so I decided to do fake delete and data showing in browser

```
my schema 
const product = new mongoose.Schema({ 
---
trash : { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

and I will show **trash: false** item only in browser
,Once user tried to delete then trash key will change to  **trash : true**

I want to show these deleted ( trash : true) items under trash tab in browser and **I want to automatically delete these trashed item after one month** from DB

**Solution**

I know there is a solution by adding `createdAt: { type: Date, expires: '1month', default: Date.now } in schema`
but this option works every item after one month from created date ,  I want to delete after one month from the change of **trash : false  to trash : true**

Comment: I think you'll need to add another field such as `trashedAt` and configure the TTL deletion on it. You'd have to set the timestamp for that field when the associated boolean is set to `true`, perhaps in some prehook middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new variable like `trashedAt` of type `date`, and then create TTL index with that as the key, as follows:

```
db.products.createIndex({ "trashedAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 })
```

30 (days) * 24 (hours) * 60 (minutes) * 60 (seconds) = 1 month

Then, while updating also mention `trashedAt: new Date()`.

```
db.products.updateOne(
   { 
      "someParameter": "someValue" 
   },
   { 
      $set: 
      { 
         "trash": true,
         "trashedAt": new Date() 
      } 
   }
)
```

or just remove `trash` completely from the document and use existence of `trashedAt` to show posts in Trash Tab, as follows:

```
db.products.find(
{ 
   "trashedAt": 
   { 
      $exists: true 
   } 
})
```

TTL needs a date or timestamp to be used, so you can't do so without creating `trashedAt: date`.

And if you add `createdAt` as the ttl index it will just delete the document one month after it was created.